# Rpi3 Bluetooth hotspot continuously from iPhone

Tags: bluetooth, internet, hotspot

I'm new to Raspberry world, I received a pi3 model as a gift.
I noted that there is a generalized problem when Wi-Fi and Bluetooth modules work at the same time, for example with a Bluetooth mouse/keyboard and a Wi-Fi internet connection.
To bypass this problem I would share my internet connection from iPhone via Bluetooth, and so in this way I can shut down the Wi-Fi module.
To do this I followed this guide, downloading Bluez:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Ac0wc-f9HI

The connection works, but every few minutes I need to reconnect manually the internet sharing (iPhone and Rpi3 remain paired all time) because Rpi stop surfing.

How could I solve?
Thanks.

Comment: This question is predicted on a falsehood. I routinely use Wifi and Bluetooth keyboard.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=154576


https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=140471


https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=151300


https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=141533


https://lb.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=145423

Comment: If you aren't aware the internet is full of incorrect "information". Not to mention that that link is years out of date. The vast bulk of us have no problems. Of course if you install random Bluetooth packages rather than using the inbuilt utilities you are on your own.

Comment: Sorry for my english @jsotola.

Comment: @Milliways have you ever tried with Wi-Fi and two Bluetooth devices all together? For example mouse + keyboard + Wi-Fi network?

Comment: @Nameless Yes. I don't routinely use a Bluetooth mouse on the Pi (because I normally have 3 Pi running at once and connecting is a pain) but my keyboard has 3 buttons to select any of the 3 and mice don't take up much room.

Comment: Why did you download bluez from youtube? You should get the correct version of it from the repo of your OS.

Comment: I downloaded software using apt-get in terminal. On youtube I only saw the guide to do this. Is it wrong?